# How can i use a variable name for a class path / use a variable in a reference statement? Python

Tags: python, class, import

I expect this is well covered already (apologies if so) but i couldnt find it in my research as i don't know exactly what to ask/how to correctly phrase the question. Basically i want to get an attribute of an instance of an object from another module but i want to call that instance as a variable. I'm using Eclipse for Python.

So in one module (of the same name as the class) i have something like this

```
class Example(object):
def __init__(self, name, width, type):
    self.name = name
    self.width = width
    self.type = type

new_example1= Example('abc', 6, 2)
```

then in another module i want to get the name of new_example1

which i can do like this

```
import Example

name = new_example.name
```

but i don't want to have to explicitly say new_example1 - I want to use a variable

If i set the variable like a string then it doesn't work e.g.

```
variable = 'new_example1'
name = variable.name
```

How should i correctly be doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) in your travels?

Comment: Ha Ha no, well my travels only started about 10 days ago - before which i had never programmed anything, let alone seen a line of Python, so i'm still very much ignorant of much of what python has to offer. Glad it's a simple one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Example
name = getattr(Example, 'new_example1').name
```

Comment: Note: this may be considered a code smell, if your variable names have some data structure to them.  It depends on your use case, but you might be better off using a dict to map names to objects rather than structured variable names.

Comment: Thanks. Think i need to read up a bit more on the predefined functions Cheers.